# Xcode 7.0.1 with CocoaPods app compile error Exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, cocoapods, xcode7

I recently upgraded to the latest Xcode and after adding a bunch of new code and fixing all my normal compile errors I got the following error.

```
PhaseScriptExecution Copy\ Pods\ Resources /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-dxseswuhgbzbluabjffcnlgzjelu/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Script-EF1179D6E7811474BD220AEA.sh
cd /Users/dpreston10/Dropbox/Pesto
/bin/sh -c /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-dxseswuhgbzbluabjffcnlgzjelu/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Script-EF1179D6E7811474BD220AEA.sh

/Users/dpreston10/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GoogleMaps.bundle
/Users/dpreston10/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle
ibtool --reference-external-strings-file --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-dxseswuhgbzbluabjffcnlgzjelu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.app/JSQMessagesViewController.nib /Users/dpreston10/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Controllers/JSQMessagesViewController.xib --sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk
2015-10-03 16:35:22.011 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[12168:7780607] CoreUI: CUICatalog: couldn't get 'kMGArtworkGraphicsFeatureSetClass' from MGCopyAnswer got '{
ArtworkDeviceIdiom = pad;
ArtworkDeviceScaleFactor = "-1";
DevicePerformanceMemoryClass = 1;
 }'
 2015-10-03 16:35:22.011 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[12168:7780607] CoreUI: CUICatalog: couldn't get 'kMGArtworkGraphicsFeatureSetFallbacks' from MGCopyAnswer got '{
ArtworkDeviceIdiom = pad;
ArtworkDeviceScaleFactor = "-1";
DevicePerformanceMemoryClass = 1;
}'
2015-10-03 16:35:22.017 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[12168:7780607] CoreUI: CUICatalog: couldn't get 'kMGArtworkGraphicsFeatureSetClass' from MGCopyAnswer got '{
ArtworkDeviceIdiom = pad;
ArtworkDeviceScaleFactor = "-1";
DevicePerformanceMemoryClass = 1;
}'2015-10-03 16:35:22.017 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[12168:7780607] CoreUI: CUICatalog: couldn't get 'kMGArtworkGraphicsFeatureSetFallbacks' from MGCopyAnswer got '{
ArtworkDeviceIdiom = pad;
ArtworkDeviceScaleFactor = "-1";
DevicePerformanceMemoryClass = 1;
}'
2015-10-03 16:35:22.024 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[12168:7780607] Please stop using -[UIToolbar _setForceTopBarAppearance:]
2015-10-03 16:35:22.024 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[12168:7780607] Please stop using -[UIToolbar _setForceTopBarAppearance:]
2015-10-03 16:35:22.025 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[12168:7780607] Error creating notification handler for simulator graphics quality override: 1000000
2015-10-03 16:35:22.035 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[12168:7780607] Please stop using -[UIToolbar _setForceTopBarAppearance:]
2015-10-03 16:35:22.035 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[12168:7780607] Please stop using -[UIToolbar _setForceTopBarAppearance:]
ibtool --reference-external-strings-file --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-dxseswuhgbzbluabjffcnlgzjelu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.app/JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming.nib /Users/dpreston10/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Views/JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming.xib --sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer//Users/dpreston10/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-resources.sh: line 25: echo: write error: Resource temporarily unavailable
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried to clean the project and also have removed Xcode/DerivedData directory for my app.

Comment: Did you open the `.xcodeproj` file instead of the `.workspace` file?

Comment: I used the .workspace to open the project.

Comment: Please let us know if you found a solution! I have this issue with Mixpanel and DMActivityInstagram

Comment: same here with mixpanel

Answer (score 26):

**Try restarting your Mac** as @ChadPodosky recommends in the comments. Did the trick for me

I also tried killing my Pods directory and `pod install`-ing again, but it didn't help.

Comment: I filed a bug report with Apple under radar://31552418.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I wanted to post what I did to get this error to clear out.

closed Xcode

In my project folder I deleted the Pods folder, Podfile.lock and the xcworkspace file.

I then reran pod install on my project folders.

Once I did this I was able to compile and run.

Comment: Tried these instructions, but they didn't work for me. Shutdown and restarted Macbook Pro, and it worked, go figure. Mine was slightly different as build and run would work fine, but archiving a Release build would run into the 'line 25: echo: write error: Resource temporarily unavailable' on a .xib in one of my Pods.

Comment: having the issue again myself. This is friggin annoying

Comment: +1 on the restart thing.... Just wasted 4 hours on this. I'm going to silently weep in the corner now...

Comment: I just started getting this with Xcode 7.3. Does anyone know if there's been any actual update on why this is happening? (btw, restart works for me, too)

Comment: do you guys use the mixpanel pod? It seems to happen just with that in my case

Comment: same thing with mixpanel pod

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I used to resolve this issue with cocoapods version 1.2.1, Xcode Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)

1. deleted the data of app in DerivedData folder.
2. deleted the Pods floder,Podfile.lock and xcworkspace file.
3. restart Mac.
4. pod install again

Or running the shell in command line.

killall Xcode

xcrun -k

xcodebuild -alltargets clean

rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"

rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang.$(whoami)/ModuleCache"

rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*

rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/*

sudo shutdown -r now