# Shell Script Invocation Error with Crashlytics Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, twitter-fabric

When i try to run a script in my xcode 8 project i get this error

Shell Script Invocation Error

I know how to install fabric in xcode, i've successfuly installed in in xcode 7 in numerous projects without issue. But now in a new project in xcode 8 i get this error.

When i delete the script there is no error at all.

The script has the following style.

```
/bin/sh
${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run API KEY OTHERKEY
```

I tried to navigate inside Fabric folder of my Pod, and runed this command

```
chmod 755 run
chmod 755 upload-symbols
chmod 755 uploadDSYM
```

With no luck.
Any idea?

P.S.

the error is the following

```
/Users/kwstasna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-fmbbqrezzwnumzdatywvlcxvqdob/Build/Intermediates/APPNAME.build/Debug-iphoneos/APPNAME.build/Script-6EA07B731D93E6ED00FD0CE8.sh: line 2: /Users/kwstasna/Desktop/open: No such file or directory
```

Comment: [xcode-7-0-1-with-cocaopods-app-compile-error-exit-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927365/xcode-7-0-1-with-cocaopods-app-compile-error-exit-code-1/45706776#45706776)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So I changed

```
${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run
```

to

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"
```

In macOS Sierra beta.

Comment: Result will be: `"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" your key`

Comment: will you please explain a littile bit about where to changed the above string.

Comment: @Nik after this post they have updated their documentation 
https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install

Comment: Thanks @KwnstantinosNatsios. I resolved this with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case after removing some library from CocoaPods script was trying to run from derived data something like:

/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ ......./Pods/Fabric/Fabric.framework/run: No such file or directory

So I cleared my derived data and it's no longer complaining